# laravel errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys

I user below tutorial for laravel categories :

[Laravel categories with dynamic deep paths](https://tjd-studio.com/blog/laravel-categories-with-dynamic-deep-paths)

I use below code same tutorial for migration :

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
```

but I have below error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'xxx'.'#sql-453_147' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

```
(SQL: alter table 'categories' add constraint 'categories_parent_id_foreign' foreign key ('parent_id') references 'categories' ('id') on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new table in Laravel. A migration will be generated like:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Instead of (in older Laravel versions):

```
$table->increments('id');
```

When using bigIncrements the foreign key expects a bigInteger instead of an integer. So your code will look like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks . is this (foreign) compulsory?

Comment: If you have gotten just one table, likely not; but there's a chance you need to link that column id to another of a different table, then its handy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the difference of the column types. So unlike the tutorial you are using `bigIncrements` which means big integer for the ID and using the default integer for the `parent_id`. Try changing the `id` to this:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

or your `parent_id` to this:

```
$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
```